# Why is Chrome extension not rendering value sent from server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a simple Chrome extension that renders text response sent from the `express.js` server. Server response is generated by running a Python script.

I've checked that text is well sent to the server when user hits the Chrome extension favicon and the response is well-generated at server side which is logged with `console.log(results[results.length-1])` in `Express.js`.

However, I'd expected the string value is well sent back to the client but the `console.log(result)` of client keeps showing `undefined`.

Which part is gone wrong to keep making the undefined retrieved `result`?

## BackEnd

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

const python = require('python-shell');

// define conda specific python
const python_path = '/Users/zachary/anaconda3/envs/abisee/bin/python';

// define sysArgs for python script
const mode = "decode";
const data_path = "/Users/zachary/Downloads/finished_files/chunked/test_000.bin";
const vocab_path = "/Users/zachary/Downloads/finished_files/vocab";
const log_root = "/Users/zachary/Downloads";
const exp_name = "pretrained_model_tf1.2.1";


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/client_txt', (req, res) => {

    const text = `${req.body.hlgt}`;

    console.log(text);

    /* python runs in express js */
    const options = {
        mode: 'text',
        pythonPath: python_path,
        pythonOptions: ['-u'],
        scriptPath: '/Users/zachary/project/pointer-generator/',

        args: [ '--hlgt', text,
                '--mode', mode,
                '--data_path', data_path,
                '--vocab_path', vocab_path,
                '--log_root', log_root,
                '--exp_name', exp_name,
                '--max_enc_steps', 400,
                '--max_dec_steps', 120,
                '--coverage', 1,
                '--single_pass', 1,
                '--batch_size', 1,
                '--beam_size', 1]

    };
    //TODO: Get return val from python script not print val
    python.PythonShell.run('run_summarization.py',
        options,
        function (err, results) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        console.log("\n ## summary ##\n" +
            results[results.length-1] + "\n"); // python "print" val stored in results
        res.send(results[results.length-1]);

        });

    /******************************/

});

const port = 8080;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port: ${port}`);
});
```

## FrontEnd

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript( {
    code: "window.getSelection().toString();"
}, async function (selection) {

    document.write(selection[0]);

    var post =
        '<form action="http://localhost:8080/client_txt" method="POST" id="hlgt_form">' +
        '<input type="hidden" id="hlgt" name="hlgt" value="">' +
        '</form>';

    document.write(post);

    document.getElementById('hlgt').value = selection[0];
    // it stores highlights into value of <input>

    var result = await document.getElementById('hlgt_form').submit();

    console.log(result);
});
```

## One Line Summary of the Question

How should I fix the above codes to receive the python-generated result from the server at front?

Comment: DOM method submit() doesn't support Promise so your await does nothing useful. Also, usually submit() navigates the page so the entire page environment is destroyed.

Comment: @wOxxOm then what would be the most compact solution for this situation?